# Find all primes $p \geq 5$ such that $6^p \cdot (p - 4)! + 10^{3p}$ is divisible by $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> Find all primes $p \geq 5$ such that $6^p \cdot (p - 4)! + 10^{3p}$ is divisible by $p$

I've tried this : First check $(p - 4)!:$
\begin{align*}
(p - 1)! &\equiv -1 \text{(mod p)}\tag{by Wilson's Theorem} \\
(p - 1)(p - 2)(p - 3)(p - 4)! &\equiv -1 \text{(mod p)} \\
(-1)(-2)(-3)(p - 4)! &\equiv -1 \text{(mod p)} \\
6(p - 4)! &\equiv 1
\end{align*}
By Fermat's Little Theorem, $6^{p - 1} \equiv 1$ (mod p), since $5 \nmid 6$ and the next primes are all greater than 6, so no prime $p \geq 5$ can divide 6. Then 
\begin{align*}
6^{p - 1}6(p - 4)! &\equiv 1 \text{(mod p)} \\
6^p(p - 4)! &\equiv 1 \text{(mod p)}
\end{align*}
Now how would I apply Fermat's Little Theorem on $10^{3p}$? I've tried writing it as $(10^p)^3$, but since $5\mid 10$, it doesnt work. Would I discard the case when $p = 5$ to be able to use the theorem?

Comment: A better version of Fermat's little theorem to use here is that $a^p\equiv a$ mod $p$ for *all* $a$ (even ones that are divisible by $p$).

Comment: $10^{3p}=1000^p\equiv 1000\pmod{p}$

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by barry 
you need to find $p$ such that $p|1000+6.(p-4)!\implies p|1000 (p-1)(p-2)(p-3)+6(p-1)!\implies p| 1000(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)-6\implies p|6006$

can you do the rest? or should i show you further?

Comment: Wouldn't I need to find a $p$ such that $p\nmid 1000$, since that is the assumption in Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: Absolutely no! $ p|a^p-a$ whatever $a$ is

Comment: So is this right?: Since $6^p(p - 4)! \equiv 1$ (mod $p$), then $6^p(p - 4)! + 10^{3p}\equiv 1001$ (mod $p$), since $1000^p \equiv 1000$. Then I need to find $p$ such that  $p| 1001$?

Comment: Yes. It is correct

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-After you have $6^p(p-4)!\equiv 1\pmod p$ you need
$$1+(10^p)^3\equiv1+10^3=1001=7\cdot11\cdot13\equiv0$$ then you have three solutions $7,11$ and $13$.